# How can I apply css on a nested element

Tags: jquery, html, css

My title of the question doesn't seem to be right as I couldnot find a right title.

I am using a owl cursol in my html. See the html code

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="ios">
   <ul class="screenshot-carousel">
     <li class="item"><img class="im" style="margin-left:1px;" src="images/screenshot1.jpg" alt="Image"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the class active get removed when the image in the center. So what I wanted to do is, when the div has class name active I want to apply a margin-top:-36px to img with the class name "im" and when there is no active class I want to apply margin-top 0px.

I tried this jQuery code to achieve that but doesn't work...

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var hasClass= $("div").hasClass("active");
         if(hasClass){
           $(".im").css("margin-top","-36px");
         }
     });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what I wanted to do is, when the div has class name active I want to apply a margin-top:-36px to img with the class name "im" and when there is no active class I want to apply margin-top 0px.

You do that with CSS: Put the class `im` on the `img`, and then use this CSS to control the `margin-top`:

```
.im {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.active .im {
    margin-top: -36px;
}
```

Simplified example:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("active", this.checked);
  var img = document.querySelector(".img");
  var style = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(img) : img.currentStyle;
  console.log("\"Image\"'s margin-top is now: " + style.marginTop);
}, false);
```

```css
.im {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.active .im {
    margin-top: -36px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
}
.img {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This is the container
  <div class="img im">
    This is the "image"
  </div>
</div>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  Make the container "active"
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks. It does apply to im class but css doesn't change when it is in .active .im .. It gives -36px; to both cases...

Comment: @sadek: If the element with `class="im"` is not inside an element with `class="active"`, it definitely will not have `margin-top: -36px` applied to it. If you could update your queston with a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button) demonstrating your problem, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Hi, yes, class="im" is inside a div which class is active. Didn't get the Stack Snippet. I think I used it.

Comment: @sadek: Right. And you said you wanted it to be `margin-top: -36px` when it was inside a div with `active` and when it wasn't you wanted `margin-top: 0px`. So that's what the above does. (Added an example.)

Comment: @sadek: *"Didn't get fet Stack Snippet. I think I used it."* "fet" isn't an English word, so I don't know what you meant by that. No, you didn't use Stack Snippets in the question. Again: The `<>` toolbar button.

Comment: Thank you. What I did is, I used another class named "center" this one also get added with active class. I tried the same css but with .center .im ... Thanks once again,,,,

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.tab-pane").each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("active")) { //* active pane
            $(".im").css("margin-top","0px"); //* rm margin for all images
            $(this).find(".im").css("margin-top","-36px"); // set margin for img of active pane
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This will run only one time on page ready, but not when carousel moves.